# Question regarding Probability of Dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

A pair of dice is thrown 180 times in a row. Find the probability that the event is 25 or more times
I should define random variable $X$ but is this binomial distribution or negative binomial distribution. I really confused the define random variable and apply the distribution function. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean this?  "Find the probability that (the total on the two dice is seven), happens at least $25$ times."

Comment: yes! (sorry for my english, i am not native)

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability that a single throw of the pair yields $7$. This is just a typical binomial distribution with success probability $p$.

Comment: Is this $P(X\ge 25)=\sum _{x=25}^{180}\left(\begin{array}{c}180\\ x\end{array}\right){\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}^{x}{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}^{180-x}$ ?

Comment: @softgliance: yes, it's $P(X\geq 25)$ but to have a numerical solution it is better to  use CLT...now I provide an answer

Comment: @tommik but total of the two dice is 7 how can define the distribution function , i am confused

Comment: The sum from $0$ to $24$ is shorter and the two sum to $1$.

Comment: For insight:  it makes no difference how complicated the definition of success is for a given trial.  All that matters is that the trials are the same and that they are independent.  This problem is exactly the same as asking "suppose we have a biased coin, that comes up $H$ with probability $\frac 16$.  If you toss it $180$ times, what is the probability that you get at least $25$ Heads?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CLT you get

$$\mathbb{P}[X\geq 25]=\mathbb{P}\left[Z\geq \frac{24.5-180/6}{\sqrt{180\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}}}\right]=\mathbb{P}[Z\geq -1.1]=1-\Phi(-1.1)\approx 86.43\%$$

this because your rv is a bernulli taking values zero and one with probability $\left\{\frac{5}{6};\frac{1}{6}\right\}$ respectively (one if the result is 7 and zero if result is not 7)

The exact result with the binomial is $\approx 86.56\%$

Nice approx with CLT, a poket calculator and the paper gaussian table...

Comment: I do not know what CLT is , sorry

Comment: @softglance The Central Limit theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: how can you find $24.5$ ?

Comment: @softglance: it's the continuity correction factor. https://www.statisticshowto.com/what-is-the-continuity-correction-factor/: If my answer has been useful you can mark it as accepted. I would appreciate

Comment: thank you, it is useful

Answer (score 0):

As lulu said in the comments, we just need to calculate the probability that a single throw of pair yields 7.

Let **A** denotes the incident that in one trial the total on the two dice is 7 and $B_{ij}$ denotes the incident that the number on the $j^{th}$ dice is i. Then we have
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^6 AB_{i1} $$
Thus we can calculate the $\mathbb{P}$(**A**)
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(A) &= \sum_{i=1}^6\mathbb{P}(AB_{i1})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^6\mathbb{P}(A|B_{i1})\mathbb{P}(B_{i1})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^6\mathbb{P}(B_{7-i,2}|B_{i1})\mathbb{P}(B_{i1})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^6\mathbb{P}(B_{7-i,2})\mathbb{P}(B_{i1})\\
&= \frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

So the answer of your question is $\sum_{i=25}^{180}\binom{180}{i}(\frac{1}{6})^{i}(\frac{5}{6})^{180-i}$, which is the same as yours.